# How do I make the Particles and Curve Guide Work?

Tags: particles

I have a sphere and added particles to it. The curve was selected. In the physics tab i selected the force type as curve guide. Why are the particles not following the path? The particles still dropping down. Whats going wrong? Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was the proposed answer useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Fix

- With the Curve selected ... Click on Path Animation which is depicted below with the Yellow Arrow.  Fix with a Click.  This might seem unexpected to you.
- Use the curve guide settings below.  There is a goal to help the OP achieve his/her desired visual. The OP can still specify the goal in the original question.
- Change the Particles to a longer lifetime. Easier Visibility.  Later Change to your Artistic needs.

[image]

Path Animation Clicked. Curve Guide Works. Spiral not so obvious. Curve Guide Settings not to OP Artistic taste perhaps.  Image above.

[image]

[image]

Curve Guide to fulfill Artistic taste of OP. Spiral Very Obvious. See the settings in the Curve Guide Panel.   2 Images Above.

[image]

Change the lifetime of particles in the particle panel of the sphere. Image Above.

[image]

Notice the Circles magically appear on the ends of the curve. Image Above.

Particles in Ascencion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen this reference video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EP0W68DVC8 He as never shown any where to click the animation and the flow of the particles also go good way. Why the particles look as if its not in the curve direction but moving in z direction only

Comment: Will the video show it move in the curve direction . But why my particles not moving in the curve direction. Looks its moving in z direction only

Comment: We can probably remove the older comments.  Now they add very little for future readers. (If any).